# Stored array data into string with comma(,)

Tags: php, mysql

[!]problem: whenever I get the data from frontend and try to insert into database...the data are inserted as a single alphabet in elective cell...but what I really needed that the whole data to be inserted in the elective cell with separated by comma(,)

[image: 1]

```
<?php
include_once '../../config/db_connection.php';
include_once '../../config/functions.php';
include "autho.php";
include('../db_mysqli.php');
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$username1 = $_POST['username'];
$username1 = preg_replace('#<script(.*?)>(.*?)</script>#is', '', $username1);
$rollno = $_POST['register_no'];
$rollno = preg_replace('#<script(.*?)>(.*?)</script>#is', '', $rollno);

$subjectcode = implode(',', $_POST['subject']);   ;

date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");

$today = date('g:ia \o\n l jS F Y');

$rollnos = array_map('strlen', $rollno);
$rollnos = min($rollnos);
if ($rollnos < 6) {
    $error = 'Roll Number is too short.';
} else {
}
if (!isset($error)) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($rollno); $i++) {
$sql = "UPDATE students SET elective='$subjectcode[$i]' WHERE register_number='$rollno[$i]'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if ($result) {
header('Location:./?edu_camp=elective_student_update&success');

        } else {
             header('Location:./?edu_camp=elective_student_update&fail');
        }
    }

} else {
    //echo "Sorry! something Wrong.";
}

}
?>
```

Comment: [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: **NOTE:** Posting images in your question isn't very useful, especially when the image has been reduced to an unreadable size.

Comment: Before you update the row in the table, you need to build the subjects as a string. So, build the string in your for loop, then *after* the for loop, perform your update.

Answer (score 2):

As the comments mentioned, you can `implode` your array into a string an insert it ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)).

Also, you're using MySQLi, but not using bound parameters which you REALLY should be using ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)).

```
// Concatenate all values together
$commaSeparatedList = implode(',',$subjectcode);
// Prepare your statement
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE students SET elective=? WHERE register_number=?");
// Bind the relevant parameters (not sure what the where clause should be here)
$stmt->bind_param('si', $commaSeparatedList, $i);
// Check if rows were affected
if ($mysqli->affected_rows > 0) {
   // Success, rows were changed
}
// Execute and close the statement object
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: already I used implode(',',$subjectcode);....but not working...whether the for loop is creating a problem..............?

Comment: You're changing variables. First you were using `$subjectcode` as an array, now after the edit, you're trying to access each element of a string in your query. So I'm not sure which variables you should be using where. Perhaps comment your code with what each intended line is supposed to be doing, so people can understand it better?